# "git pull --rebase" leads to "Cannot rebase onto multiple branches"

Tags: git, github, branch, git-rebase, git-pull

So, my work environment has precisely one branch with a remote companion on Github.  I'm trying to do `git pull --rebase` in order to prevent `git push` from creating merge commit messages that don't provide new information to others working on this project and just gum up the works.  But when I try that, it gives me this:

```
From https://github.com/our_profile/our_repository
 * branch            HEAD        -> FETCH_HEAD
Cannot rebase onto multiple branches
```

And the pull aborts. Calling `git branch` informs me that I have only one branch on my local machine, so what's going on?

Comment: Yeah, and executing *'git pull --rebase'* for the second time works! That`s because during the first action git fetched the data, so that remote and local master branches started indicating the same commit.

Answer (score 38):

Try specifying exactly what remote branch you want to pull:

```
git pull --rebase origin branch
```

Alternatively you can also `git fetch` all changes from the remote repository first, and then rebase manually:

```
git rebase origin/branch
```

Comment: This nearly worked, but it ended up causing problems involving lots of files being marked for deletion.  I had to go in to git GUI to save the work I had done on them.

Comment: Do you know why this situation occurred?

Comment: Is there a way to find what branches have the issue?

Answer (score 18):

In my case, I had to be both specific about which remote **and** move the `--rebase` flag to the end of the command.

So:
`git pull origin master --rebase`

Learned from this answer: [Git: Cannot rebase onto multiple branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842492/git-cannot-rebase-onto-multiple-branches)

Answer (score -16):

The simplest solution I discovered was to use TortoiseGit's contextual menu item "Git Sync".  In it is a means to do fetch & rebase on your current working branch.

Comment: I thought git pull did a fetch by default which is evident by all the fetch messaging that comes in. What does the above add?