# Cannot rebase onto multiple branches

Tags: git

When I'm trying to pull and rebase **single** branch, git is failing with `Cannot rebase onto multiple branches`.

I've browsed existing questions and all of them suggest specifying the branch to avoid the error. In my case it's still failing:

```
$ git pull --rebase origin master
From github.com:xxx/yyy
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Cannot rebase onto multiple branches
```

Running the command for 2-3 times helps and the repository gets pulled.

My git config:

```
[color]
        ui = true
[core]
        pager = less -r
        autocrlf = input
        excludesfile = /Users/kir/.gitignore_global
        editor = /usr/bin/vim
[push]
        default = simple
[filter "lfs"]
        clean = git-lfs clean %f
        smudge = git-lfs smudge %f
        required = true
```

Git version: 2.7.2 (latest from Brew)

Comment: Did you do `git fetch` before rebasing?

Answer (score 14):

Try to set the rebase at the end of the command instead as the first flag:

```
git pull origin branch --rebase
```

If this is still doesnt work split it into 2 commands (`pull = fetch + merge`).

```
# fetch all the remote data
git fetch --all --prune

# no execute a merge command
git merge origin/branch --rebase
```

Comment: Moving the --rebase to the end actually works. The question is why?

Answer (score 0):

I get same error in my custom bash script while `git pull origin branch --rebase`

My solution is using `git fetch --all --prune && git rebase origin/branch` instead of `git pull origin branch --rebase`